# What happens to both accepted-answers during a merge?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, merged-questions

What takes place when a question having an accepted answer is merged with another question which also has an accepted answer? Is one kept, and the other discarded?

If so, what determines which? Is the master answer (belonging to the question that is not deleted after merge) given priority?

Comment: According to Jeff (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34774/show-some-kind-of-evidence-trail-on-merged-or-deleted-questions/34833#34833), merges are rare and only if both questions are 100% duplicate in every way. Chances of both also having identical accepted answers are even rarer.

Comment: @o.k.w: Good call, but I think this is a great question and deserves an official answer from Jeff. Unfortunately, with him traveling, I'm not sure we'll get it too quickly.

Comment: @SotU, oh yes, I'm waiting.... :P

Comment: Can't we test it? Let me know, I'll ask two test questions, you answer, I'll accept them, and then you merge them

Comment: @Downvoter: Just be sure to be creative on the questions!

Answer (score 7):

Currently, the removed question's accepted answer is unaccepted when it's moved to the master question.