# How can I see my merged question? Why was it merged?

Tags: support, status-completed, merged-questions

I know it is offtopic and I will delete my question as soon as I get any answer, but somebody merged my question. The question was opened for the whole day, but when I got 3 reopens and edited my question for asking for 2 more reopens to reopen my question, somebody merged my question. It was about efficiency during the programming. Why did somebody merge my question and didn't let it remain closed?

I found there many good answers although it was closed and now I can see absolutely nothing.

Comment: Tom, questions about SO itself belong on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ (where they need not be deleted).

Comment: This belongs on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I ask why it was deleted. Ok, I admit it was offtopic, but there was many good answers and it should be just closed, not deleted. Or I am wrong?

Comment: "I know it is offtopic" - then why post?

Comment: You've got 9 deleted questions, but none that matches that description. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I have none deleted questions apart from this one I think, you made a mistake. And here is my former thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939167/increasing-your-efficiency-during-programming

Comment: SO is not your personal help desk, is it? Hence, I like questions being merged to create a nice Q&A archive. (Which, for me, for the above question only leaves the part: how to find the resulting merged question and its answers.)

Comment: @Bart and mizipzor, the "belongs on" comment seems to [have resulted in a repost](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/51774/revisions). I feel comments like that [are not too helpful at all](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18494/belongs-on-comments)...

Comment: @Arjan, Thats right, but this time I think because of Migration bug. I am seeing there is 7 people voted to migrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2940144/revisions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing would be extremely, extraordinarily rare.

Also, I don't see any deleted questions on your account over the last few months.

Did you ask it under an anonymous account while not logged in? Basically I can't find this question you're talking about, so you need to prove to us that it ever existed :)

edit: this question was merged with another question.

edit: we now handle question merging in a much more sane way -- both questions are retained, one is a stub, and all answers are migrated into the merged question. If the stub is deleted, we 301 redirect to the merge target.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939167/increasing-your-efficiency-during-programming 
Also, you can find it on google.
Thank you for your support.

Comment: @tom looks like it was merged with another question, so you'll need to search for a unique text string in one of the answers.

Comment: Are we all in agreement that "it was merged with another question, so you'll need to search for a unique text string [to find it]" is kind of crazy? I've been searching the feature-requests looking for requests to leave a link like closing as a duplicate does, and I can't see any consensus on if that's actually going to happen, I find answers like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34774/show-some-kind-of-evidence-trail-on-merged-or-deleted-questions/34833#34833)

Comment: @Jeff: Suggesting to [merge duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50069/why-are-we-deleting-instead-of-merging/50106#50106) is what probably keyed this off.

Answer (score 2):

I think following was your question

> Yeah, yeah, I know, it is a little
>   bit of offtopic, but let''s try.
>
> So, I want to increase my efficiency
>   during my programming as much as
>   possible to programme as fast and
>   sensibly as possiblle. What do you do
>   before starting coding? Drink a lot of
>   coffee, energy drinks? Do you listen
>   to music during programming or you
>   keep quite?
>
> Share your
>   ideas.
>
> **2 more reopens and this
>   thread will be reopened!
>   :)**

From that, I would say that following questions are quite duplicate with some of the post in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51097/the-great-question-deletion-audit-of-2010) list, so might be merged with one of them

- Drink a lot of coffee, energy drinks?
- Do you listen to music during programming or you keep quite?

And when the question got merged, only answers can be merged and original question is literally destroyed, according to Jeff [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50761/when-a-question-is-merged-redirect-original-question-url-to-new-one-automaticall).

**Edit**: your question probabaly merged with following question

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411394/how-to-become-a-faster-programmer

Comment: Kudos to Jonathan for taking the time to merge, but if it were up to me then just deleting is appropriate for these kind of questions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Only offensive questions and spam are deleted. But maybe there was some technical trouble and SO couldn't save your quesion.

I suggest to look up the URL of the question in your browser's cache and contact an admin why it was deleted (they can see deleted questions). You can find an admin by looking at the Users page. Look for someone with a little blue diamond beside the name.

Comment: There were no offensive questions and spam at all.

Comment: This isn't quite right. Only offensive and spam type questions (and possibly special cases that get the attention of diamond moderators) are deleted suddenly without a 2 day or longer period of being closed but universally visible.

Comment: How can I contact admin? There is no button "send message" or smth like that.

Comment: @Tom: see the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Take a look at the questions that are being closed http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last2days.  Most of them have gone through reopen cycles, meaning that at least 5 people with 10k rep voted to reopen them.  That surely means that they're not "spam or offensive"